# Error in getting filepath from URI in Android

Tags: java, android, file, uri

This is a code which returns a file path given the URI.

```
public String getPath(Uri uri) {
    String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
    //String[] projection = { MediaColumns.DATA };

    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null, null);
    int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaColumns.DATA);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    return cursor.getString(column_index);
}
```

This works for images in Gallery because the projection is MediaStore.Images. How do get file path for all other directories? The file can be a document type and it can be in any location of sd card. What projection should I search for the file path?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is here. It checks for projections in `Images` only. So if file is of different type, you will not get a path. `Exception` will be returned. Also its better to use:

```
 int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaColumns.DATA);
```

and use your onw `try-catch` block. This will prevent your app from crashing

Comment: Thanks! I had solved it already. This was what i did and some other small tweaks to make it work :)